# How do I change the name of a fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I rename an existing fortress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rename a Dwarf?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-can-i-rename-a-dwarf)

Comment: @MichelAyres a dwarf is not a fortress.

Comment: LOL @antony.trupe **1.** You can ask why someone down-vote your question if you have intention on modify it. **2.** The down-voters doesn't have the obligation on post a comment saying why (but it's polite and helpful) **3.** No, I usually don't donw-vote without leaving a comment or up-voting a comment that fit's what I think. **4.** No I didn't down-vote you. **5.** I believe that you receive down-votes because your question doesn't show very enforce to be created.

Comment: @MichelAyres "doesn't show very enforce"? what does that mean?

Comment: Hmm, how can I put this... That was an example ¬.¬" ... I can't know why someone down-voted you, your question was probably in the "Low quality posts" in the review session. where it says "This question was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." This is why I use that as example. (NOTE, I'M NOT SAYING THAT YOU WERE THERE OR IT'S BECAUSE OF THIS!) Just an example ... nothing more, your make a comment like I did something that I didn't then you deleted it. Sorry dude, not answering your comments again =/ Go to the chat if you want it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Dwarf Fortress wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Fortress_name):

> You can choose the name of your own
> fortress during the Embark process.
> When you reach the stage where you are
> deciding on your founder's skills and
> starting items, press Shift+F to
> choose your fortress name. You will be
> given a semi-random name
> automatically. Fortress names are
> always compounds of two dwarven words.
> If you choose to pick your own name,
> you can craft a fortress name that
> would otherwise be rejected by the
> name generator.

Comment: To add: I don't think there's a way to change the name of a fortress after embark, though you might be able to during reclaim.

Comment: I don't believe you can change the name during reclaim. I've never seen the option on my play throughs. Once a player embarks to a fortress, the name is set in cotton candy. In the future, renaming a site may be added as feature, but I wouldn't bet my neck beard on that.