# Is there anyway to change the surname of dwarfs?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

It seems like there isn't, apart from programmatically changing the first two items of the words array using DFusion(as indicated by the following [arQAde question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-can-i-rename-a-dwarf)). However that question is a bit old, so **I was wandering if anybody came up with anything new?**

The reason why I would like this is that I would like to easily indicate familial bonds(who's whose family, using patriarchal rules for surname inheritance). It doesn't make sense to me for a child of a bloke to not bear their surname.

A work around could be created by using the nickname field as dynasty name holder, and selecting to display the nickname in the middle.